# Сохранение docker-образа в архив .tar средствами ansible из локального образа (на control node)

Tags: docker, ansible

Пытаюсь на основном узле ansible собрать docker образ с экспортированием его в .tar (для дальнейшей заливки на управляемые хосты и запуска)

Имеется: Ubuntu 22 LTS docker 20.10.21 ansible [core 2.14.2]

Плейбук:

```
---
- name: DEPLOY 
  hosts: all
  tasks:

  - name: build docker image
    local_action:
      module: community.docker.docker_image
      build:
        path: ../
      name: buh_img
      push: false
      source: build

  - name: save image to tar file
    local_action:
      module: community.docker.docker_image
      archive_path: buh_docker_image.tar
      state: present
      name: buh_img
      source: local
```

при запуске ansible-playbook docker-образ собирается без проблем (проверив командой "docker image ls" - видим требуемый "buh_img")

Но второй таск работает с переменным успехом. Может выполниться успешно, а может выдать:

> TASK [save image to tar file]
> ************************************************************************** fatal: [vm01 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg":
> "Error getting image buh_img:latest -
> UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)"}

И непонятно почему такая разница в результате (от чего зависит) пробовал и "systemctl restart docker" перед запуском playbook делать и добавлять в него:

```
- name: restart docker
    local_action:
      module: ansible.builtin.service
      name: docker
      state: restarted

  - name: reload docker
    local_action: 
      module: ansible.builtin.service
      name: docker
      state: reloaded
```

В чем причина? И как добиться стабильного сохранения созданного образа в tar-архив?

Comment: `local_action` - depricated, если память не изменяет. Попробуй штатный синтаксис с `delegate_to: localhost`.

Comment: А выхлоп `buh_img` можно добавить?

Comment: @donRumata                                                                                                                                      
Какой именно выхлоп? Сам image еще не запускался

Comment: @donRumata                                                                                                                                      
Какой именно выхлоп? Сам image еще не запускался. По результатам таска [build docker image] Ansible выводит  ok: [vm01 -> localhost]   или changed: [vm01 -> localhost]
в зависимости от того был уже этот образ или нет

Comment: А, я с `register` перепутал, сорян. Ну тогда можно сорс того, что хочешь сбилдить?